# Why am I not getting any values displayed in my ui-grid dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have this following code for ui-grid column Definition:

```
{ name: "carrier_influence_group", displayName: "Carrier influence group", enableCellEdit: true, showSortMenu: false,
                editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', editDropDownOptionsArray: [ { id: 11, value: 'Medium' }, { id: 12, value: 'Large' }],
                    editDropdownIdLabel: 'id',editDropdownValueLabel: 'name'}
```

I am binding the name of these object to  the column.

Every thing is fine normally. The grid as such renders correctly. But when I dbl click to edit this row, the text in this row disappears. A dropdown appears but it has no option to select from.
I tried changing my array to:

`[ { id: 11, name: 'Medium' }, { id: 12, name: 'Large' }]`

What is missing here. I have seen this official [code](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable). Seems like all is similar except for a filter. I do not need any such filter. Is it necessary to have one. The official docs do not mention anything about it.

Already referred `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323540/showing-readable-data-in-ui-grid-with-editable-drop-down-cell`

Comment: What are the errors in console?

Comment: None at all....

Comment: Add ur code preferably a executable one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to try - it should be `editDropdownOptionsArray` not editDropDownOptionsArray (note the case).